# Creating Multidimenional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I add arrays into an existing array item?

For instance:

```
$user[$user->id] = array(//values);
```

But if that user needs another array added, I want all data to fall under that user ID in the array.

I want to store orders a user has made, so I can look up all orders on the fly by user ID in the $user array above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user[$user->id]['orders'] = array();
```

Or

```
$user[$user->id] = array(
    'orders' => array(
        array(// data for order #1),
        array(// data for order #2),
        array(// data for order #3)
    );
);

// Looping over the orders
foreach($user[$user->id]['orders'] as $order) {
    // Do something with the order
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
$user[$id] = array_merge($user[$id], array(//values));
```

Comment: It all came out [empty string]

Answer (score 0):

Give the orders a key

`$user[$user->id] = array(
  "orders" => array(values)
);`

Comment: I am looping over orders, and each user may have multiple orders. Wouldn't the key be overwritten?

Comment: @Kevin - I updated my answer to show multiple orders, but it should be clear by now how arrays within arrays works.

Comment: @kevin - agree with mellowsoon